# banner ads disappear from android application

Tags: android, admob

I published an android application and it has banner ads.
when application published on google play store banner ads display in application but after one week banner ads disappears.
what is the problem then ? and how to solve it ?

Comment: Did you check the "Policy Center" section of AdMob if they found any violations? Did they send you an email saying they restricted your ads? Did you link the AdMob app to the Google Play Store app? (via your AdMob page). Do you have an app-ads.txt? Did you modify it by adding admob as an advertising source?

Comment: they didn't sent any mails to me, and I didn't have app-ads.txt this is first app for me and I already linked admob app to the google play store

Answer (score 0):

Most probably, admob has placed limits on your account. If your app is new, this is not uncommon. Make sure the implementation of your app is correct (for ads), and wait for a few days. If you are not indulged in any activities that violate Google's ad policies, the ads will start displaying again. It may take upto a month. Also, please consider reading about things on the web first before asking on StackOverflow

Answer (score 0):

Banner ads will only show on App installed through Play Store and wait for a minute to let it load ads(this solved the above described problem once that I was too facing)

Comment: ads already displayed when application published on google paly store but after one week ads disappears

Comment: wait for a minute or two to load those ads depending on your location.
or try re installing the app once again from play store.

If this fixes your problem then please accept this answer i will update accordingly.

Comment: if this comment resolves your query can you mark it as the accepted solution?